# Multiply 2 numpy arrays and return the sum for each dimension

Tags: python, numpy

Hello my title name might be slightly off, so let me try and explain it simple. I have the following 2 np arrays:

```
a = np.array([[3,2],[1,4],[12,4]])
b = np.array([1,2])
```

A consists of 3 "lists". The first value in each list is multiplied with the value of the first number in b. Second number in each list multiplied with second value in b etc.

Desired calculcation below for the desired output:

[1*3+2*2],[1*1+4*2],[1*12+4*2], meaning:

```
[7, 9, 20]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply do `a.sum(1)*b`.

Comment: I edited my post since I had specified that it needed to work for other dimensions than just 2*2, e.g 3*2 as well.

Comment: Your new desired result doesn't make any sense I can see. What's the rule for what gets multiplied by what?

Comment: If this needs to work for more dimensions please add an example of what that would look like

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe you want the dot product (`np.dot(a,b)`) ?

Comment: That doesn't match your example computation.

Comment: yes it was wrong sorry. fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = np.array([[3,2],[1,4],[12,4]])
b = np.array([1,2])
np.sum(a * b, axis=1)
```

output

```
array([ 7,  9, 20])
```

This utilizes [numpy's broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)